# Обновление данных без перезагрузки php

Tags: php, обновление

У меня есть баланс на сайте, который берется из сессии sql:

```
<a class = "balance"><?= $_SESSION['user']['credits'] ?></a>
```

После нажатия на кнопку средства переводятся, баланс уменьшается. Всё считается правильно, в таблице SQL всё выводится сразу, но на сайте, чтобы обновить баланс, нужно перезайти на аккаунт. Как сделать так, чтобы баланс обновлялся сразу?

Comment: указано ведь откуда вы его выводите, вот туда и запишите новое значение

Comment: Вам нужен JS. Создаете переменную, которая хранит разницу и минусует от баланса(при нажатии кнопки переменная увеличивается). Второй вариант - запрос суммы вынести в rest запрос и обновлять, правда тут тоже нужен js.

Comment: @SwaD при чем тут js ? у него баланс в сессии хранится и заполняется только при логине.

Comment: Сделайте лучше динамическое обновление баланса через JS + PHP. JS просто будет обращаться к файлу php, где проверяется авторизация и в json формате возвращает значение баланса, потом просто обновляйте значение в контейнере с классом  .balance

Comment: Можете написать код???